# Use OR among with #ifdef

Tags: c++, c

I suppose you can add code which will get executed only if 2 terms are simultaneously declared this way:

```
#ifdef X
#ifdef Y

//code to execute

#endif
#endif
```

I wonder if there's a way to execute the code if at least X or Y is declared (also consider xor), something like:

```
#ifdef X or #ifdef Y

// code

#endif
```

?

Comment: You can ignore parenthesis if you wants: `#if defined X || defined Y` , don't forget endif

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Using `defined`:

```
#if defined(X) || defined(Y)
```

Comment: So I observed I can even use ^ for an exclusive or.

Comment: Interesting, didn't know that, thanks for the find.

Comment: @gg.kaspersky That's probably because `defined(X)` will expand to an integer 1 or 0, so technically any operator that works with integer types will work here. You can even do `#if defined(X) + defined(Y)` to get an "or" effect.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `operator||` like this:

```
#if defined(X) || defined(Y)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with:

```
#if defined(X) || defined(Y)
...
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to say:

```
#if defined(X) || defined(Y)
```

The following 2 forms are equivalent:

```
#ifdef identifier
#if defined identifier
```